# #pragma once equivalent for c++builder

Tags: c++, precompiled-headers, c++builder-2009

Is there anything equivalent to `#pragma once` for Codegear RAD Studio 2009?

I am using the precompiled header wizard and I would like to know if it is still necessary to use include guards when including header files?

Comment: what would have speaken against trying it out yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support for #pragma once was added in C++Builder 2010
In C++Builder 2009 and earlier, the unknown pragma will simply be ignored. I would suggest using

```
#ifndef X 
#define X
//code 
#endif
```

style header guards in the versions of C++Builder that do not support #pragma once.

Answer (score 1):

Rad Studio supports `#pragma once`, along with [all of the following](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pragma_Directives_Overview_Index).

Comment: Excellent. The installed help must have been out of date.

Comment: Please note that support for #pragma once was only added in C++Builder 2010 and was not available in C++Builder 2009 and earlier.

Comment: oh in that case - unmarking as correct answer. @David you should post that comment as the correct answer.

Comment: @David see follow up question regarding if 2009 has header-include-guard-optimisation, even though it doesn't use the `#pragma once` directive. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233401/are-redundant-include-guards-necessary

Comment: I'm not getting anything under http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pragma_Directives_Overview_Index -> 503 Service Unavailable