# Intentional compiler warnings for Visual C++ that appear in Error List?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings, pragma

How can you create a compiler warning (in the model of #error, except as a warning) on purpose in Visual C++ that will show up on the Error List with the correct file and line number?

GCC and other compilers offer #warning, but the MSVC compiler does not.

The "solution" at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/155196 does not parse in the Visual Studio error list.

Comment: looks like you are confused about what exactly is Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's an S.O. sort of question.  I also would like to know what others would do better.

Comment: @Juliano:  What exactly do you find objectionable about this question?  It's most certainly on-topic and interesting.  It might be a duplicate, but I couldn't find a duplicate question.

Comment: @James: He posted the question *and* the answer. It looked like a blog post or something. Now he edited it, but it is still strange. Take a look at the revision history to understand.

Comment: @Juliano: The FAQ specifically says that this kind of question is just fine (even question/answer type) and has said so since the beta.

Comment: @Jason do what I suggested and look at the revision history of the question. He posted the answer in the question area, which was clearly wrong. Now he edited the question. Geez...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add this to your common include file (ex, stdafx.h):

```
#define __STR2__(x) #x
#define __STR1__(x) __STR2__(x)
#define __LOC__ __FILE__ "("__STR1__(__LINE__)") : warning W0000: #pragma VSWARNING: "
#define VSWARNING(x)  message(__LOC__ x)
```

Use this like:

```
#pragma VSWARNING("Is this correct?!?!")
```

The compiler will output:

```
c:\dir\file.h(11) : warning W0000: #pragma VSWARNING: Is this correct?!?!
```

And the Error List tab will show the warning nicely in the table:

```
Type       Num   Description                                             File    Line
[Warning]  13    warning W0000: #pragma VSWARNING: Is this correct?!?!   file.h  11
```

exactly like a normal Visual Studio compiler warning.

Comment: I use a similar implementation to this (I posted it [in response to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703528/what-code-have-you-written-with-pragma-you-found-useful/2706693#2706693)).  I didn't realize that Visual C++ would macro replace the text of a pragma directive; that's very cool.

Comment: On a related note, you can also use "error" instead of "warning" in the output text; this causes compilation to fail (like `#error` does), but allows compilation to continue to the end of the translation unit (which is extraordinarily useful in some scenarios).

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a silly answer to your question, but often, if I need to add an intentional warning, I will type something like:

```
#pragma asdfkljasdlfjasklfjklasjdfklj
```

which issues a `Unknown Pragma` warning with line number and all.

Comment: That doesn't print the actual message in the compiler output and Error List, though.  Only "unknown pragma" appears.